# Totally confused by YouTube / Google+ integration

Tags: youtube, google-plus, google-account

HELP! I'm losing my mind.

At some point YouTube had me choose to create a new "channel" linked to a new "google+" profile -- maybe I had the option to keep my old gmail-linked channel -- I can't remember. When I created the new account I used a temporary name, which I now want to change, and cannot figure out how to do so.

Now I have two YouTube accounts (channels? profiles? WTF?) -- which I cannot merge.

YouTube docs say to click "change" next to channel name in Advanced Settings, but that just pops up a link to the G+ profile, where there is no option to change the name at all.

I find having these two profiles very annoying -- YT always asks "as whom" I want to use YT. I just want to use my Gmail-linked profile.

But the second profile now has a bunch of uploads (which I need), and my viewing history.

And for some reason only this second profile gives me the option to monetize content and upload custom thumbnails!

Is there anything I can do??

Comment: Unfortunately, what you are asking for is not possible. Youtube has no such feature.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding of your situation:

You have two YouTube accounts, Account 1 and Account 2. Account 1 is merged with Google+ A, and Account 2 is merged with Google+ B.

To answer your question directly, I'm afraid it's impossible to transfer Account 1 to Google+ B. But I can suggest you another reasonable solution:

You can go to the Google+ page of YouTube 1 and add Google+ B as a manager, which technically equals being another partial-owner of the page with the abilities of doing almost everything with it.

Comment: "Account 1 is merged with Google+ A, and Account 2 is merged with Google+ B." I don't think this is what is being stated. The OP sounds a lot like my situation - I have an myname@gmail.com profile and a "tubedogg" profile. I cannot login directly to the "tubedogg" profile - I have to login as myname@gmail.com and select it from the "Use Youtube as..." menu (where the choices are between myname@gmail.com and tubedogg). I remember merging a tubedogg YouTube account with myname@gmail.com Google account a long while ago, but I don't know why tubedogg and myname@gmail.com are not the same account.